# Altair interactive charts doesn't plot anything-python3

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, visual-studio-code, altair

I am trying to run the example: [Multi-Line Tooltip](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_tooltip.html) and this run well without mistakes but dosen't show me anything, it must give me a interactive plot. I am using Python 3.8.0 installed with anaconda3 in Visual Studio Code and have installed all [dependencies and additional dependencies](https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/installation.html). Mi OS is W10.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
source = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100, 3), 0).round(2),
                    columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=pd.RangeIndex(100, name='x'))
source = source.reset_index().melt('x', var_name='category', value_name='y')

# Create a selection that chooses the nearest point & selects based on x-value
nearest = alt.selection(type='single', nearest=True, on='mouseover',
                        fields=['x'], empty='none')

# The basic line
line = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(interpolate='basis').encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    color='category:N'
)

# Transparent selectors across the chart. This is what tells us
# the x-value of the cursor
selectors = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    opacity=alt.value(0),
).add_selection(
    nearest
)

# Draw points on the line, and highlight based on selection
points = line.mark_point().encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(1), alt.value(0))
)

# Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, 'y:Q', alt.value(' '))
)

# Draw a rule at the location of the selection
rules = alt.Chart(source).mark_rule(color='gray').encode(
    x='x:Q',
).transform_filter(
    nearest
)

# Put the five layers into a chart and bind the data
alt.layer(
    line, selectors, points, rules, text
).properties(
    width=600, height=300
)
```

Comment: Try using ``alt.renderers.enable('mimetype')``. I believe that VSCode supports this. You also need to make certain you have an updated version of the VSCode Python extension.

Comment: i tryed but nothing happened